# AngularJS wait for ajax request to complete

Tags: ajax, angularjs, intervals

I have a AJAX request that's invoked in an interval of every 10 seconds, but I want to be able to call the AJAX only after my previous request is completed.

```
$interval(function () {
            $scope.getContent(2);
        }, 10000);
```

With the above code, the ajax request is performed every 10 seconds irrespective of my previous request being completed. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Use Angular promise; $q

Comment: use promise chaining in angularjs to achieve this

Comment: So you want to keep calling every 10 seconds even after the ajax request returns successfully? At what point do you stop calling? Do you just keep calling every 10 seconds for the entire life span of your app or is there a limit?

Comment: thanks I am looking at promise now! @Matt, its through-out the life span of the app, there is no limit, I already have the logic to destroy the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve:

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/1rb7VJYX30s9exSbcufD?p=preview)

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $interval, $http, $timeout) {

  // create variable to store interval promise
  var interval;

  $scope.callCount  = 0;
  $scope.pending    = false
  $scope.start      = start;
  $scope.stop       = stop;
  $scope.getContent = getContent;


  function getContent(){

    $scope.pending    = true;
    $scope.callCount  += 1;
    return $http
      .get('foo.json')
      .then(function(response){

        console.log('response', response);

        $scope.pending = false;

        // call stop() if you don't want to 
        // continue calling

        // call stop() then start()
        // if you want to call again
        // immediately and continue calling
        // every 10 seconds

      })
      .catch(function(){
        $scope.pending = false;
      });

    // comment out the $http call above
    // and uncomment the $timeout code
    // below to test that start() does not
    // call getContent() if pending 
    // still true

    // $scope.pending = true;
    // $scope.callCount  += 1;

    // return $timeout(function(){
    //   $scope.pending = false;
    // }, 11000)  

  }

  function start(){

    if(angular.isDefined(interval)) return;

    $scope.getContent();

    interval = $interval(function() {
        if(!$scope.pending){
          $scope.getContent();
        }
    }, 10000);

  }

  function stop(){
    if(angular.isDefined(interval)) {
        console.log('stopping')
        $interval.cancel(interval);
        interval = undefined;
    }
  }

});
```

**html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Call Count: {{callCount}}</p>
    <span ng-show="pending">pending...</span>
    <button ng-click="start()">Start</button>
    <button ng-click="stop()">Stop</button>
  </body>
```

Comment: pretty much what you have written above, without of-course the start and stop buttons :)

Answer (score -1):

`$interval(function () {
            if($scope.flag){
               $scope.getContent(2);
               $scope.flag=false;
           }
 }, 10000);`
and set `$scope.flag` value to `true` when your previous request is completed(i.e in callback).